# Make PHP files on a USB flash drive load in portable Notepad++ by default?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Portable file association for USB sticks?](https://superuser.com/questions/381763/portable-file-association-for-usb-sticks)

I have a USB flash drive, called CLINIC, that contains a portable copy of Notepad++ for Windows. CLINIC also contain some PHP files that I want to edit. I only want to edit them in the copy of Notepad++ on CLINIC.

How can I make it so that when I open a PHP file on CLINIC, the default application used is Notepad++? It must use this default on any Windows computer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do this ONLY for files on the USB drive. You can set the default for ALL files with the same extension and/or mime type but not make it specific to a drive.

Instead, get into the habit of starting the copy of NP++ and in its settings, set a default project to point to the drive.